# Why is react-redux required if redux library can be directly used in react?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, react-redux

I was trying to use redux in my react application but I see I can explicitly use redux in my application without using the react-redux library.

```
const redux = require('redux');
```

I am wondering then why do we even need react-redux library in our environment?
Can someone help me with this?

Comment: [There is documentation explaining what it does.](https://react-redux.js.org/introduction/getting-started).

Comment: Well technically you don't need it. You could subscribe to the store yourself. However react-redux solves the issue of connecting your components to the store for you and therefore eases development.

Comment: If you remove it, does your code still work as expected?  If so then it sounds like you indeed do not need it for your project.

Comment: @GBDGBDA How do you get your components to re-render when global redux state changes?

Comment: thanks, I got it now, I didn't start with react until now I was just exploring the code base and came to know about this package react-redux. Sorry if it was too lame beginner question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In short:

React-redux is what makes your components rerender when Redux state that is being rendered by your component changes.

Of course you could also do `store.getState().foo.bar` in your component, but then you would have to track manually when that state changes and rerender your component. Otherwise, it would always stay the same and never update.

If you instead use `useSelector(state => state.foo.bar)`, your component will always rerender when `state.foo.bar` changes, so you don't have to track that yourself.

Answer (score 2):

Redux is an UI-library-agnostic state management library.
React is a state-management-agnostic UI library.

React-Redux is glue between the two. You don't need it, but you'd have to implement the glue (hooks/HOCs) yourself.

Comment: You should probably show the code you're using to magically use Redux and React together without anything implemented by yourself.

Answer (score 0):

`react-redux` contains in particular the `Provider` component and the `useDispatch` and `useSelector` hooks.
If you are using them, you're using `react-redux`. If you are not using them, you're missing out a lot, so I suggest you do.